# sqlite3 dose not understand NULL to create primary key column in table

Tags: python, database, sqlite, primary-key

I tried to create table in my database and add PRIMARY KEY to my table by using sqlite3 library, But sqlite3 did not understand NULL

**this my code:**

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    view()

def view():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('books.db')
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT \* FROM book")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

connect()

insert('anybook','anyperson',1918,6384515345)
print(view())
```

**I expected the output to be**

```
[(1,'anybook','anyperson',1918,6384515345)]
```

**But it was:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\CORSES\The Python Mega Course\000. Projects\APPs\4. BookStore\Book Store\BackEnd.py", line 28, in <module>
    insert('anybook','anyperson',1918,6384515345)
  File "e:\CORSES\The Python Mega Course\000. Projects\APPs\4. BookStore\Book Store\BackEnd.py", line 13, in insert
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
sqlite3.OperationalError: table book has 4 columns but 5 values were supplied
```

Comment: You have misdiagnosed the problem.  The problem is you did `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS`, and the table that's currently in the database is an earlier version which only has 4 columns.  Instead if `IF NOT EXISTS`, do `DROP TABLE book` and then `CREATE TABLE book`.

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book`

Comment: I've noticed that the use of `IF NOT EXISTS` is almost always a red flag.